# Can Social Security in USA be funded outside of FICA taxes?

Tags: united-states, social-security

> Social Security is **primarily** funded through dedicated payroll taxes called Federal Insurance Contributions Act tax (FICA). (src: Wikipedia)

Is there anything in the law (or a court finding) that makes this a requirement?

I know that in some cases general revenues were used (2011/2012) to finance the Fund.

**Is there anything on the books** that would prevent government from simply slashing FICA tax to 0% (it being "regressive" as thus explained as being morally wrong, as a justification) and making 100% of payments to SS be from general revenue?

Comment: I know that SS owns trillions in intergovernmental transfers. these "investments" earn interest and will eventually need to be repaid to the SSA. Since that money must be repaid from the general fund, I dont see why FICA couldnt be completely eliminated. (barring some statute that could obviously be overturned.)

Comment: @user1873 - I would consider "money derived from FICA, even as interest on it", as being part of "FICA", for the purposes of this question. Point is, is there anything aside from political opposition that would stop a President from issuing an executive order (or Congress passing a law) making FICA 0%?

Comment: As Social Security draws down its trust fund (FICA), it sells bonds back to the Treasury. The money it gets for those bonds comes from the general fund (from http://www.motherjones.com/kevin-drum/2012/11/no-social-security-trust-fund-isnt-fiction)

Comment: @SeanCheshire - accounting wise, they are already on the balance sheet as liabilities, to match the money gotten as assets from bond sales. Balance sheet wise it's a wash (just time delayed), so shouldn't impact the answer to this question.

Comment: In theory SSI is a retirement investment.  The more you put in the more you get out.  So if you pay none in then you are not entitled to take any out at retirement.

Comment: @Chad - is that a legal opinion or a moral one? I don't think there's any requirement to put anything into SSI - e.g. any recent elderly immigrant would get SSI despite never having paid into it. Ditto people who never paid a cent in federal income taxes due to low income or being on welfare.

Comment: @DVK - It is how SSI works.  There are some exceptions for people with disabilities where they receive money based on what they could have contributed, but yes you have to contribute to be eligible for SSI at retirement.

Answer (score 2):

[Trust Funds](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/401):
sections **(a)** and **(b)** define the funds, and where the money comes from (payroll taxes).
Section **(h)** is what defines which fund is used to pay each part of Social Security (emphasis mine)

> [(h)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/401#h) Benefit payments
>   Benefit payments required to be made under section [423](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/423) of this title, and benefit payments required to be made under subsection (b), (c), or (d) of section [402](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/402) of this title to individuals entitled to benefits on the basis of the wages and self-employment income of an individual entitled to disability insurance benefits, shall be made **only from the Federal Disability Insurance Trust Fund**. All other benefit payments required to be made under this subchapter (other than section [426](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/426) of this title) shall be made **only from the Federal Old-Age and Survivors Insurance Trust Fund**.

402: Old-age and survivors insurance benefit payments
423: Disability insurance benefit payments
426: Entitlement to hospital insurance benefits

(to your comment on interest, it is defined in section **(f)** that this does go back into the fund)

Comment: Wait, then how do they justify using general budget for paying 2011/2012 benefits when there was shortfall?

Comment: well, I don't know how they **justify** it, but in H.R.2419
Food, Conservation, and Energy Act of 2008, SEC. 15361. PROTECTION OF SOCIAL SECURITY., it allowed for payments into the fund. No doubt there's other such appropriations on other bills

Comment: @DVK - Because they used the trust fund to pay general budget debts instead of taking on other debt in the 1970ish-2009(It ran dry in 2009) - What they did in 2012 was actually serviced the debt they owed the trust fund instead of just carring the interest they were accruing against it over)

Comment: @SeanCheshire - Oh, so it was specific rules for a specific allocation in those years, no some general mechanism that automatically kicks in? Curious. I'll ask for justification in a separate Q.

Comment: @Chad - Hm... that wasn't an impression I got from Wiki's wording. I asked separately: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/what-was-the-legal-justification-for-h-r-2419-protection-of-social-security